# Why sorting mixed list does not work

Tags: python-3.x

Been scratching my head this one for quite some time:

```
mixed = [-131.23, 33213, 4454, 566, -33, 465. -377.312, 5.6656]
print(sorted(mixed, key=float))
```

Expected output is:

```
[-131.23, -377.312, -33, 5.6656, 566, 4454, 33213]
```

Instead I'm always getting this

```
[-131.23, -33, 5.6656, 87.68799999999999, 566, 4454, 33213]
```

Why -337.312 gets converted to 87.6879999999?? I assume each element gets converted to float when using key=float...so why this behaviour?

Comment: It's nothing to do with the sorting; look at the original list... Also it's not clear why that's your expected output, those numbers aren't in order.

Comment: `465. -377.312` is a single entry in your list (no comma).

Comment: Simple typographical error.

Comment: The expected output should be `[-377.312, -131.23, -33, 5.6656, 465, 566, 4454, 33213]` and not the one you posted. You have mistyped a number in the original list `465. -377.312,` there is a dot instead of a comma there! I would have expected a parsing error though. You should report it.

Comment: @alec_djinn why would that be a parsing error? It's perfectly legal syntax, not a bug.

Comment: @alec_djinn `-` can be unary or binary.

Comment: @jonrsharpe a negative sign after a dot? In which math this is a legal syntax? mmm.. wait, I see... it parses it as a subtraction. But still, I would have complained about a dot not followed by anything instead of converting it to .0 automatically.

Comment: @alec_djinn it's not "after a dot", it's after a floating point number. The fractional "digitpart" is optional, see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#floating-point-literals

Comment: just a typo, thanks guys!

Comment: So unaccept the answer and delete the question, this is not useful to other users. Note that the most basic debugging (*"is it like that **before** I sort it?"*) might have helped.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, I got it. Still, it bothers me a bit but it's just my feeling. It is clear in the docs.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I can't delete it, won't let me

Comment: Because the answer has upvotes, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your original data:

```
>>> [-131.23, 33213, 4454, 566, -33, 465. -377.312, 5.6656]
[-131.23, 33213, 4454, 566, -33, 87.68799999999999, 5.6656]
```

because you forgot the comma and this does the substraction:

```
>>> 465. -377.312
87.68799999999999
```

Just add the comma:

```
>>> sorted([-131.23, 33213, 4454, 566, -33, 465, -377.312, 5.6656])
[-377.312, -131.23, -33, 5.6656, 465, 566, 4454, 33213]
```

Comment: correct, just a typo, thanks!!!!

Comment: So VTC as a typo.